# I am facing issue to set redirect url to react page from identityserver4 while register

Tags: asp.net-core, react-router, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using IdentityServer4 (3.1.1) & ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Razor Pages.

[image: Project Sructure]

Below is my startup.cs code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(option =>
        {
            option.User = new UserOptions { RequireUniqueEmail = true };
            option.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            option.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            option.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
            option.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            option.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            option.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            option.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
            option.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
        {
            iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
            options.Authentication = new AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(10), // ID server cookie timeout set to 10 hours
                CookieSlidingExpiration = true
            };
        })
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
              b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

            // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
            options.EnableTokenCleanup = false;
            options.TokenCleanupInterval = 3600;
        })
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
        services.AddRazorPages(options =>
        {
            //options.AllowAreas = true;
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
        });

        //configures the application cookie to redirect on challenge, etc.
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        });
        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        InitializeDatabase(app);
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Below is my React code in Login.JS to redirect

```
  redirectToRegister() {
this.redirectToApiAuthorizationPath(
  `${ApplicationPaths.IdentityRegisterPath}?${
    QueryParameterNames.ReturnUrl
  }=${encodeURI(ApplicationPaths.Login)}`
);}
```

Below is Authorize.js Code

```
var settings = {
        authority: "https://localhost:44306",
        client_id: "Application.UI",
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/authentication/login-callback",
        response_type: "code",
        scope: "openid profile WebApi",
        post_logout_redirect_uri:
            "http://localhost:3000/authentication/logout-callback"
    };
```

When click on the register link navigate to the below URL

> https://localhost:44306/identity/Account/register?returnUrl=/authentication/login

When finally click on the register will navigate to the below link

> https://localhost:44306/authentication/login

While it should be

> http://localhost:3000/authentication/login
>   So, it can navigate to the proper URL with return url of
>   https://localhost:44306/authentication/login-callback

While using the localhost or other direct link prompt the below error

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
```

InvalidOperationException: The supplied URL is not local. A URL with an absolute path is considered local if it does not have a host/authority part. URLs using virtual paths ('~/') are also local.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.LocalRedirectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, LocalRedirectResult result)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: The supplied URL is not local. A URL with an absolute path is considered local if it does not have a host/authority part. URLs using virtual paths ('~/') are also local.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.LocalRedirectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, LocalRedirectResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.LocalRedirectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
System.InvalidOperationException: The supplied URL is not local. A URL with an absolute path is considered local if it does not have a host/authority part. URLs using virtual paths ('~/') are also local.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.LocalRedirectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, LocalRedirectResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.LocalRedirectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved with the help of [Nan Yu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5751404/nan-yu) [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60445939/5470366) Please check the comments section of it:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("/Identity/Account/Login");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email });
                }
                else
                {
                    // this will redirect mannually to the address where you suppose to redirect
                    return Redirect("http://localhost:3000");                      
                }
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect user to Idenity Server for register user using ASP.NET Core identity , but after registering asp.net core identity will not automatically redirect to your client's page according to the url you pass in query string  , you should customize the logic to make the register method redirect user back to client's login url(use absolute url) you passed .

Comment: I try to add abolute path but it prompt following error: This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: localhost:44306/home/… HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: You should firstly redirect back to client(http://localhost:3000) after registering user  , and client will redirect to identity server for login again if the path/route need authentication.

Comment: I tried following Link in Register User: **https://localhost:44306/Identity/Account/Register?returnUrl=http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000**
It prompt Following Error **InvalidOperationException: The supplied URL is not local. A URL with an absolute path is considered local if it does not have a host/authority part. URLs using virtual paths ('~/') are also local.**

Comment: As i said , you should redirect back to client (your angular app) , not redirect to identity server's login page after user register . Identity server login need parameters which should provide by your client app . After register user on Identity server-->back to client -->client route need authentication--> auto redirect to identity server's login page for sign in .

Comment: This is my register URL: https://localhost:44306/Identity/Account/Register?returnUrl=http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000
and in parameters i used returnUrl=http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000

Comment: You should manally redirect user to your return url . asp.net core identity won't help redirect .

Comment: Can you please share the manually way (I didnt understand) any reference

Comment: Thank you: for manually i used the following line  
`return Redirect("http://localhost:3000");`
it solve my problem.
In Register page: `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)`
where i need to redirect i add the above given line for redirect solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

you should redirect your user to https://localhost:44306/connect/authorize, then if your users isn't registred yet, he will click on register button.

change url of this 'redirectToRegister' method to 'https://localhost:44306/connect/authorize'

Comment: While using this solution return following error: **This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44306/home/error?errorId=CfDJ8KjnDZqHjIpLlywqcl62AuR8dpFvNkKGfBG3sr6I6GS_8iy3-liV01hbb_C38FzpMM4OTdfSwcSvgs5r-7yEjMhsLlEQ6rwp2cr-Wekhn2F3S-wdCTZYbdmdoSmd-_A6hvN0kA3wF8unkmCD3FtWtZ4hpdhT0ntK7LHHwJiIxG6aw7Wabkj2BXzvWs4If8z41uksDsxft9p73-2UqRk6eHEjZvL7wdu4ulryYNhX6RAQCbNCYRjSoxSNk5gcESo9dRQP3LwQAOPNzLEi2qB2g53RTmqEfuMZ_RuAloO967qLNAjF9E7wgMAA737fHLlcSg
HTTP ERROR 404**

Comment: when you redirect to authorize/connect you pass some parameters to it, one of them is redirecturl, so after login, identityserver redirect your user to tour react page, also passing this parameters should be done with your client tools.

Comment: it prompt following error 404: This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44306/home/error?errorId=CfDJ8KjnDZqHjIpLlywqcl62AuR8dpFvNkKGfBG3sr6I6GS_8iy3-liV01hbb_C38FzpMM4OTdfSwcSvgs5r-7yEjMhsLlEQ6rwp2cr-Wekhn2F3S-wdCTZYbdmdoSmd-_A6hvN0kA3wF8unkmCD3FtWtZ4hpdhT0ntK7LHHwJiIxG6aw7Wabkj2BXzvWs4If8z41uksDsxft9p73-2UqRk6eHEjZvL7wdu4ulryYNhX6RAQCbNCYRjSoxSNk5gcESo9dRQP3LwQAOPNzLEi2qB2g53RTmqEfuMZ_RuAloO967qLNAjF9E7wgMAA737fHLlcSg
HTTP ERROR 404